# What is the best way to handle the dependency tree when implementing a custom Mediator?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm implementing a custom Mediator for wso2esb-4.7.0.  Obviously as my classes will be running within the context of wso2esb, I expect them to utilise the same deps.
wso2esb has, for whatever curious reason, been deployed with custom builds of its dependencies.  Eg. They expect you to point at their custom mvn repostiory and use artefacts suffixed with "-wso2vn"  Eg. axis2-kernel/1.6.1-wso2v9

This has worked for most of the dependencies which get shared with the wso release, however wso2esb uses its own logging artefact with its own versions of sl4j and commons-logging:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
        <artifactId>logging</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

The problem is that this doesn't exist in their mvn repo, which contains the pom files but not the jar:
http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/org/wso2/carbon/logging/4.1.0/

I'm going to use the non-wso2 specific versions of those jars for now, but will need to resolve this for deployment.

Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the above dependency is the aggregate module of the logging related dependencies used in WSO2 carbon products. Therefore it will have a pom file only.

Use the following dependency for your requirement.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.logging</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The maven repo link can be found [here](http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/org/wso2/carbon/org.wso2.carbon.logging/4.1.0/).